# How to increase the selectbox dropdown width in ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad

I am trying to increase the width of the drop-down of the select box in Ipad... when i increase the width of the select-box, the drop-down is not increasing accordingly..i have tried by increasing the width and font-size of the option and select box.. but there is no impact on the width of the drop-down. Please suggest.

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? so we can see what is the problem

Comment: It's just the normal select box... could you please let me know how to increase the dropdown width of any select box in iOS..

Comment: If is an specific select (I mean if you have more than 1), you could use the id in the CSS like this `#MyID{
 width:150px;   
}`

Comment: Here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/rd6czvb0/